# Kendo Listview, added checkboxes, added a select all, will check and uncheck all once, will not check all again.

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, checkbox

I would like some help with this.  I have a Kendo Listview:

```
 <form id="frmChk">
        @(Html.Kendo().ListView<thieme_ws3.Models.QaTestModel>(Model)
        .Name("testList")
        .TagName("fieldset")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "panel panel-primary panel-body" })
        .ClientTemplateId("template")
        )
        <br />
    </form>
```

Where I have added checkboxes to the information brought in:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
        <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.CheckBox("cb_#:Id#", new { @class = ".item", id = "cb_#:Id#" })  #=Name#
        </div>
    </script>
```

I have added a select all checkbox:

```
 <label id="checkAll" class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" /> Select all
    </label>
```

And added this to fire it:

```
 $('#all').on('click', function (e) {
    //alert("I'm clicked!" + this.checked);
    var testList = $("#testList").data("kendoListView");
    var dataItems = testList.dataItems();

    //do thought to wrap the loop in a do while, caused the browser to stop
    {

        for (i = 0; i <= dataItems.length - 1; i++) {
            //alert(dataItems[i].id);
            var cb = $("#cb_" + dataItems[i].Id);
            if (this.checked) {
                cb.attr("checked", "checked");
            }
            else {

                (cb.removeAttr("checked"));
            }

        }
    }
    })
```

It will work once, checking all boxes and unchecking all boxes but when I check the select all again, it will not select the others.  I am certain it is something small I am overlooking, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead (assuming the checkboxes are descendants of `#testlist`):

```
$('#all').on('change', function (e) {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $("#testList").find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', isChecked);
})
```